# CSP blocking resources error appears when the DevTools of the Browser is open

Tags: html, css, content-security-policy

I set some Content Security Policies on my website and it all seems to work as expected. However I have two  tags including some stylesheets and I have added a random nonce to them:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.0.0/legacy/ol.css" type="text/css" nonce="@ViewData[Constants.ViewDataForRandomNonce]">
<!--webfonts-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Average+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' nonce="@ViewData[Constants.ViewDataForRandomNonce]">
<!--//webfonts-->
```

When I open the page the resources seems to be loaded and all works as expected. However, if I open the DevTools of the Browser(Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Edge) errors that these resources are blocked appears:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.0.0/legacy/ol.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-tafkuumpf7umcwUlySiRUQI201ARRpx0a6woKsteas9hywtxVshmpJUREdoycXT5'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
    
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Average+Sans' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-tafkuumpf7umcwUlySiRUQI201ARRpx0a6woKsteas9hywtxVshmpJUREdoycXT5'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
```

If I reload the page while the DevTools is open the error disappear. But as soon as I close and then open again the DevTools, the error appears.

This happens on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge (I don't have any other browsers on my PC). On Firefox the errors don't disappear even after I reload the page.

One maybe important thing is that I am testing on the localhost, if that could be it.

Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the CDN addresses to the CSP list of allowed hosts. Kinda weird because it already had a nounce and it was working